# JS currentTime of video HTMLelement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, video, redmine

I have the problem in redmine. Video attachments absolutly cannot be seeking. I deleted all js scripts working on videos and tried to change 'currentTime'. It doesn't work. I checked it with different video files, changed webm/mp4, tried to use 'video-js'. Video still cannot be seeking.

Simplisticaly this code do nothing

```
media = document.querySelector('video')
console.log(media.duration) // 119.03
media.currentTime = 10 // do nothing
```

The event 'seeking' works only at the beggining.

Comment: It works https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/4j0h2vfd/

Comment: This should work) But don't. Its mystic, and I want to get any ideas why is it so.
stop, pause, duration - are Ok. Event 'ended' works, but 'seeking' works only at the beginning. currentTime do nothing, event didn't run. And simple constructions from jsfiddle doesnt. Really thank you for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, code above should work.
Have your tried on different browsers.

```js
const media = document.querySelector('video');
media.currentTime = 5;
```

```html
<video src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid5.mp4" width='240' controls></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decide my trouble for rails. Its need to add for video file requests:

```
headers['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
```

Good luck, guys!